# How to handle the end of the audio?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I use [media response] (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) for play audio. 
When the audio finishes, I see `actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS` in actions on google simulator. But the dialogflow does not send this intent to my web hook.

How do I set up an dialogflow agent  to get this intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From [doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses):**
If you're using Dialogflow, replace actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS with the action name specified in the intent which receives the actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS event.

[image]